# Fast way to check if object is in the side of a segment

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a line segment from $p_1$ to $p_2$. I also have the normal vector to the segment, represented as the blue vector in the image. My question is: is there a fast way to check if a point is in the "left side" of the segment? The "left side" is represented by the yellow area, where the points $b$ and $c$ are. The other points $a$, $d$ and $e$, when checked, should be tagged as outsiders.

I already came up with a solution (that works for my case): drawing a very big rectangle to represent this yellow area and check if the points are inside the rectangle, but I'm looking for a faster way, something simple and fast that I'm able to execute every frame of my application.

[image]

Comment: You can find the equation of line $P_1P_2$. Let the equation be $f(x)$.Then for example you have to test $a$. Take the $x$ coordinate of $a$ and plug that into equation of line.  If $f(a_x)\lt a_y$, then the point lies on the right side.Similarly, if $f(a_x)\gt a_y)$, the point lies on the left.

Comment: I thought about this but how would I test $e$? It's on the correct side but not inside the yellow region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate all points so that $p_1$ goes to the origin $(0,0)$, then rotate/rescale so that $p_2$ goes to $(1,0)$. This is easily done using the complex representation,

$$\bar p\to\frac{\bar p-\bar p_1}{\bar p_2-\bar p_1}=\bar a\bar p+\bar b$$

where the coefficients $\bar a,\bar b$ are computed once for all.

Then a point belongs to the yellow area when

$$0\le x\le 1\land y\le0.$$

Expressed in terms of the original $x,y$,

$$\color{green}{0\le a_xx-a_yy+b_x\le1\land a_yx+a_xy+b_y\le0}.$$

[image]

The test costs $8$ arithmetic operations and three comparisons per point. (In fact a little less because in some cases you can conclude with partial evaluation.)
Unless preprocessing of the points is allowed, I don't think you can solve this much faster.

---

On second thoughts, you can spare a little more. Assume that $|a_x|>|b_x|$. Then rewrite the conditions as

$$0\le x-\frac{a_y}{a_x}y+\frac{b_x}{a_x}\le\frac1{a_x}\land\frac{a_y}{a_x}x+y+\frac{b_y}{a_x}\le0$$ and finally, with new constants

$$\color{green}{u\le x-ry\le v\land rx+y\le w}.$$
At most $4$ arithmetic operations and $3$ comparisons per point. If on average a fraction $\alpha$ of the points fall inside of the whole stripe defined by the segment, the test can be organized to require $2(1+\alpha)$ operations and $\dfrac32(1+\alpha)$ comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $\vec b$ for the blue vector. For a point $x\in\Bbb R^2$, we want to check three things: that the angle between $\vec b$ and $(x-p_1)$ is obtuse, that the angle between $(x-p_1)$ and $(p_1-p_2)$ is acute, and that the angle between $(x-p_2)$ and $(p_1-p_2)$ is acute. We can calculate these with the scalar product: the set of points "left" of the segment is 
$$\left\{x\in\Bbb R^2\left|\begin{array}{l}
\langle x-p_1,\vec b\rangle\leq 0\\
\langle x-p_1,p_1-p_2\rangle\geq 0\\
\langle x-p_2,p_2-p_2\rangle\geq 0
\end{array}\right.\right\}$$
This should be relatively light on calculations, as the scalar product is a quadratic expression in the coordinates of the points involved.

Answer (score 0):

This $2D$ formula:

$$res=(y2−y1)⋅(x3−x1)−(x2−x1)⋅(y3−y1)$$

will give a positive value if $(x3,y3)$
is at right of line $P1→P2$, or a negative value for point at left.

Notice that changing the segment direction ($P2→P1$ instead of $P1→P2$) changes the sign of $res$.

**EDIT**

Let's define that a point $X=\{x3,y3\}$ is outside of the segment $P1,P2$ if it does not lies inside the two lines passing through end points and perpendicular to the segment.

This can be tested by watching the two angles $\angle X\;P1\;P2$ and $\angle X\;P2\;P1$

The angles can be calculated by the Law of Cosines or its cousin Dot Product.

If **both** angles are $<=\pi /2$ then the point is "inside" the segment.

Comment: Would $e$ be considered correct according to this formula?

Comment: The formula works with a line instead of segment. I don't know how left/right of a segment would be different from a line. For point $e$, just test it; it will surely work.

Comment: This was the reason I asked for a segment instead of a line, I want $e$ to be correctly tagged as an outsider.