# Which side of two intersecting lines I am in

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

what's the easiest way to know on which side of two intersecting lines a point is? The two lines are defined by 3 points as follows:
[image]

Comment: Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be vectors parallel with the lines. Then if we call your vector $w$, look at the signs of the dot products $w \cdot v_1$ and $w \cdot v_2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast way to check if object is in the side of a segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682385/fast-way-to-check-if-object-is-in-the-side-of-a-segment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a clear definition of "side" for a line defined by two points, it's impossible to answer this question. So let me give such a definition:

If $A = (x_0, y_0)$ and $B = (x_1, y_1)$ are *distinct* points, and $(p, q)$ is any point of the plane, we can say that $(p, q)$ is on the "good" side of the line defined by $A$ and $B$ if...
$$
s = (p-x_0, q - x_0) \cdot (y_0 - y_1, x_1 - x_0) > 0.
$$
If $s < 0$, then we're on the bad side; and if $s = 0$, then we're on the line itself.

Now when you've got a pair of lines, there are four possibilities for a test point $(a, b)$, assuming it's on neither line: (good, good), (bad, good), (good, bad), and (bad, bad).

In the case of your diagram above, with $L1$ defined by $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$, and $L2$ defined by $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, the "good (for L1), good (for L2)" region is to the upper left, and the "bad, bad" is to the lower right. The region in the upper right is "bad, good", and lower left is "good, bad".

Comment: What if we restrict the classifications to only two regions. let's say the (good, good) region as in your description and any other region. How the classification would work in this case?

Comment: Then I think you compute the value $s$ for each of the two lines, and if both $s$-values are positive, you fall in the (good, good) region; if either is negative (or both are), then you fall outside the (good, good) region.

Comment: Yes, that right but for a general approach, where the intersection point could be relatively in any position to the other two points, the + + signs won't be always right to detect the interested area. I guess relative signs to somehow reference signs need to be understood first for a general approach.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of your comment, but if you can express it really clearly, you should consider asking a new question. (It's OK to reference this one, but it's generally a bad idea to add stuff to a question once it's already been answered.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Write the equations of the two lines, say, like

$$y = a_1x + b_1 $$
$$y = a_2x + b_2 $$

2. To check the relative position of point $(x_p,y_p)$ with respect to the two lines, plug $x_p$ in the equations of the lines to calculate $y_{check_1}$ and $y_{check_2}$ as follows:

$$y_{check_1} = a_1x_p + b_1 $$
$$y_{check_2} = a_2x_p + b_2 $$

3. Calculate $y_p - y_{check_1}$ and $y_p - y_{check_2}$ . Each of these values tells you if the point is above or below the respective line. The four combinations of signs of these two values correspond to the four zones created by these two lines in the plane

Note1: The exceptional case where one of the lines is vertical is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Note2: The exceptional case where the two lines are parallel is left as an exercise for the interested reader.